# add_filter not adding the filter

Tags: filters

i am adding a filter at the end of my themes functions.php

```
if( !function_exists( 'mars_widget_post_ids' ) ){
    /**
     * @param array $query
     * @param string $widget_id
     */
    function mars_widget_post_ids( $query, $widget_id ) {
        if( $widget_id == '2046' ){
            $query['post__in'] = array( 1,4,5,6 );
        }
        return $query;
    }
    add_filter( 'mars_main_widget_args' , 'mars_widget_post_ids', 100, 2);

/* checking the wp_filters */

}

  global $wp_filter;
  var_dump($wp_filter);
```

In this code above after add_filter, i dump the array $wp_filters to browser.

there is no value with mars_main_widget_args
. the add_filter function returns "1".

Comment: you should do your filter check and adding of the filter outside the function exists if statement

Comment: sorry i dont get you. can you explain little more.

Comment: You are doing an if statement to check if the function exists, and if it doesn't you define it. This is where your if statement should end. The other bits of code should be outside, not inside the statement. If that function is already defined, your debug statement and the `add_filter` call will never happen.

Comment: I have edit the question. I have brought the debug statement outside the if statement. I want to add_filter only if the function does not exist. I know that there is  no other function. But still as a code practice i have added that.

Comment: Your code works for me perfectly fine. What purpose does `function_exists()` check serve? Are you defining function elsewhere as well?

Comment: How did you declare the filter. Because add_filter is not declaring the filter. Also the function_exists() is used for when using it in child theme